# Code completion for Firebase in VS code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code, intellisense

On [this video](http://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=57s) Typescript is used for code completion. 
I followed the instructions from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) and have Typescript working with the Hello World example. I have no idea what to do next to have code completion for Firebase.

**How can I get code completion for Firebase in VS Code?**

**Update 1**:

I created my Firebase project with the following commands in the VS code terminal: `firebase init`, `firebase init functions`. So I would also want the code completion to work in the functions/index.ts file that I will have to create, just saying.

Then I did `npm init` and as sugested:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/firebase
```

In the root directory of the project now I have the `node_module` directory with only `@types/firebase` as content and this package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "My Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Does something",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/firebase": "^2.4.31"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Somebody",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I also created a `index.ts` file to test but when I type `firebase.` no code completion. What is the next step to get the code completion?

**Update 2**:

.vscode/tasks.json:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "tsc",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
  "showOutput": "silent",
  "isBackground": true,
  "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", 
        "sourceMap": true
    }    
}
```

**Still no code completion!**

**Update 3**:

The beginning of the `functions/index.ts` file where I am interested to see the code completion:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

The `import * as firebase from 'firebase'` part is from [this video](http://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=57s) where I saw the code completion working. I would also want the code completion to work in `public/app.ts` the client side file.

Answer (score 10):

I use at the beginning of the functions/index.ts

`import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');`

and it works.

Comment: The code I got from samples had const functions = require(...). Changing const to import did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: well in type script it works.. but I stuck with no intelisense in javascript

Answer (score 4):

please install firebase [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/firebase) to get firebase code completion

```
       npm install --save-dev @types/firebase
```

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion. I'm still missing something because no code completion yet.

Comment: you will also have to do `tsc init`

Comment: With `tsc init` I get this error: `error TS6053: File 'init.ts' not found`. Finally I created an `index.ts`(because this where I will need the most the code completion) file and did this: `tsc .\functions\index.ts`. Still no luck.

Comment: i meant to say you need tsconfig.json which is created from tsc init

Comment: I created the file. Updated the question. Still no code completion.

Comment: I updated the question. Basically I have this at the beginning of the file: `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

Comment: This is deprecated now since Firebase API provides its own type definitions.