# Firebase JavaScript Code Complete/Intellisense

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I started to develop Firebase apps and was using VSCode. I followed some on line tutorials but was unable to get code completion/intellisense working in vscode.

There seems to be nothing on the internet on this. I found a few posts but nothing work.
Such as this one: [Code completion for Firebase in VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274471/code-completion-for-firebase-in-vs-code)

Here is a sample of my code, querying a collection of document:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (evt)=> { 

const app = firebase.app()
console.log(app)

const db = firebase.firestore()

const myToDoThing = db.collection("thingstodo").doc("firstthing")
//get the document
myToDoThing.get()
.then(doc=>{
    const data = doc.data()
    console.log(data)
    //console.log(data.createAt )
})

//Get live update of the document
myToDoThing.onSnapshot(doc=>{
    const data = doc.data()
    console.log(data)
})
})
```